# return to position in array after exit

Tags: arrays, bash

Apparently I wasn't clear when I last asked this, I'll try again.

I have an array full of values, lets call them `primenumbers.txt`

I have a bash script lets call it `primechecker`

The script will take each and every value and in the array and 1 at a time and run it through. However I want to be able to stop `primechecker` at some point in processing this array; lets call it X and restart the script in a way that the start position in the array is X+1.

If there is some further clarification need please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you store the current index in a file in /tmp and check for that file on startup:

```
for i in nums; do
  echo $i > /tmp/marker
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a global env variable and store possition in it.
For Example:

- add this "`export ARRAY_POS=""`" to ./.profile
- relogin and then
- update you script like this:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  for i in nums; do
  ARRAY_POS="$i"
  ...
  done
  ```